# deb packages for former "ni" stack

Tags: ros, kinect, openni-node, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

looking at the list of ROS diamondback packages, there are two packages for the former "ni" stack: ros-diamondback-openni-kinect (0.1.1) and ros-diamondback-openni-ros (0.1.0), to me they both seem to install more or less the same stuff. Which should one use, or is this just an artefact?

Best,

Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9333/deb-packages-for-former-%22ni%22-stack/) by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openni_kinect was temporariliy named openni_ros.  It was renamed in later releases.  It will be deleted as soon as all released stacks not longer depend on it.  More information was announced on the mailing list at http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110308.224900.56b0ced3.en.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2